# What is the recommended workflow for presenting company files to users via forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

Our customer (*company*) is looking for a way to integrate the customizable viewer capabilities of forge into a website as part of an interactive technical manual for their products, designed in Autodesk Inventor.

I've followed the getting started and self-help paths on the forge website, and downloaded the sdk samples and about a dozen other user/developer samples. Nothing I can find gives me a good solution for presenting *company* files to the end user. They show how to give the user access to their own cloud files via Autodesk login or direct upload to forge buckets. I've looked for ways to access 360/Team files, but all those paths are based on having a user log in.

I can't find anything that matches what we are attempting to do. The functionality I'm looking for would be like the A360 Share via Embed but with a customizable viewer via forge.

TLDR: What is the proper workflow for giving end users controlled access to view our Inventor files on a website via the forge viewer, or is this not the intended usage for the product?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand what you want - as far I got it, you want to allow anonymous users without login to see your files stored on an Autodesk HUB requiring user access? These viewables will be hosted on your website, but users would not need to login to see them. Did I got this correctly? If this is the case, then you would need to proxy the viewer calls to your server which will grant access to the files. I can give you instructions to do this is this is what you want.

Comment: The samples I have found either request the user upload a file or log into a file storage hub. We do not want the users files, we want the user to be able to interact with and view our files. 
     1. Where is the *best* place to store these files so that they load quickly in the viewer but can be updated easily if the design changes? Our web server, the cloud, somewhere else?
     2. Is there a sample, or can one be provided, that would demonstrate the functionality needed to accomplish the viewer using our files with the suggested storage method (from 1.)?

Comment: You always need to start from a seed file. That seed file needs to be uploaded one way or another and translated. Once it is translated, you can delete the seed file since the viewer does not use it. Once a seed file has been translated, the view can display it, and your users can interact with the model in the viewer. They do not access in any way to the seed file.