# How to list files from Autodesk HUB without manual Autodesk login?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I would like to have specified files from an Autodesk HUB, say Fusion Team, viewable on our company website without the need to login into an Autodesk account.

- Can we implement/store the login credentials for a specific HUB in the backend to allow those files as viewable-read?

The first comment from Cyrille on this question is exactly what I would like to know about:

[What is the recommended workflow for presenting company files to users via forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725991/what-is-the-recommended-workflow-for-presenting-company-files-to-users-via-forge)

The Hubs Browser tutorial does this functionality but redirects to the Autodesk login page. I would like the same functionality without the manual login step & to use the credentials that I specify.

https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/

This question & answer are a few years old but seem to say that it is not possible:

[Automatic Login to myHub with Autodesk Forge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102897/automatic-login-to-myhub-with-autodesk-forge)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using a 2-legged OAuth instead of 3-legged one (where user login is required). When you look at the documentation of endpoints such as [GET /hubs](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/) or [GET /hubs/:hub_id/projects](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-GET/), you'll see that the **Authentication Context** is **user context optional**, which means that this endpoint can be called with either 2-legged or 3-legged access token.